# Minimum number and its index in a random array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The problem is to find the minimum number in the random array 50 numbers. It should be between 0-100 and its index. I don't know what's the wrong with my code. It prints more than one minimum value and I haven't found a way to make limit to the array:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of a link to a screenshot of the code.

Comment: It does not seem that its pointing toward more then one, its just finding a min that is less then previous min it found as it loops... you need to output the result when you finished searching... after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not generating random number properly.

To find a random number in range 0..99,use

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(100);
```

Try this

```
    public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = new int[50];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        int minimum = arr[0];
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (minimum > arr[j])
                minimum = arr[j];
        }
        System.out.println("Minimum value-->" + minimum);

    }
}
```

**Output**

Output will vary as per the generated number.In my case,I got

```
Minimum value-->4
```

Comment: Ok what about printing the value many times , I just want it to print once

Comment: Great Man I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't print inside the "for" loop.

The loop determines which value is the minimum.
Once it has ended, print the result.

```
for{
...
...
}

System.out.println(Minimum);
```

Comment: the same result even when print it outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
int[] a = ...; // after random for

int min = a[0];
int minIndex = 0;        
for(int i = 1; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if(a[i] < min) {
       min = a[i];    
       minIndex = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(minIndex);
```

Comment: You can start the loop at `i = 1`

Comment: yes, but it isn't bug, just one fake iteration. Fixed